# mootools double dollar equivalent in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, mootools, dollar-sign

I have a line of code that uses mootools to get an array of elements with the given selectors

```
var menuItems =  $$('#container .menu');
```

I need to convert this to jquery but can't find a solution. I have tried jQuery('#container .menu') but it doesn't return an array.

Is there a way to use '.find()' from jquery on the whole document ? (since I don't have a parent element to make it like parent.find()..)

Any other suggestion is also most welcome

Comment: does `$('#container .menu')` not return and array of elements which match the selector?

Comment: you want to convert .menu children to an array ?

Answer (score 3):

With jQuery your statement:

```
jQuery('#container .menu')
```

will return a jQuery object that contains all matching elements where you can access the individual DOM elements with array-like syntax:

```
var menuItems = jQuery('#container .menu');

menuItems.length        // gives a count of how many matched
menuItems[0]            // the first matching element

// but you can also use jQuery methods on the object
menuItems.hide();
```

If you want an actual array rather than an array-like object you can use jQuery's [`.toArray()` method](http://api.jquery.com/toArray/):

```
var menutItemsArray = jQuery('#container .menu').toArray();
```

Why don't you try [one of the jQuery tutorials](http://docs.jquery.com/Tutorials%3aHow_jQuery_Works) available at the [jQuery website](http://jquery.com/)?

Answer (score 0):

If you absolutely need it as an array, rather than working with the jQuery object returned by the selector, take a look at the [`.toArray()`](http://api.jquery.com/toArray/) function.